# Nginx Internal Server Error

Tags: nginx, python, web, uwsgi, flask

I am new to NGINX and uwsgi and Im deploying my first python web application. Having tried numerous times, I get an internal server error. There may be something wrong with my configurations but i can't see what!

I have posted the contents of my configurations:
/etc/uwsgi/apps-available/uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /srv/www/searcular/venv/
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
chmod-socket = 666
pp=/srv/www/searcular/venv/
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
module = manage
callable = FlaskApp
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/searcular: (i have *'d the domain)

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     *******.com;
    access_log /srv/www/searcular/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/searcular/logs/error.log;

    location / {
        #uwsgi_pass      127.0.0.1:9001;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param     UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;
        uwsgi_param     SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

    }

    location /static {
        root   /srv/www/searcular/venv/FlaskApp/static/;
        index  index.html index.htm;

    }

}
```

Having tried everything, I can not get the application to run.

My application structure is:
venv
  - FlaskApp  (main app)
  - bin
  - local
  - lib
  - manage.py (application to run)

Question:
1. where have my configurations gone wrong?

Comment: What is in your error log?

Comment: @MichaelHampton There is no error in the error log regarding this issue

Comment: Then how did you get an "internal server error"?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The message appears on the webpage, and not in the error log files

Comment: Are you sure you looked at the right file?

Comment: the latest in the access log is:
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 32 "-" "Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com/)". But the error log has not been updated.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using the apache2 server and following the instructions on this link:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

It now works